Does the EPEL version specify its compatibility to the specific RHEL version?
For example, does EPEL-8 only work on RHEL-8 and not RHEL-7?

Yes. This is generally how all packages work. It might be possible that a package build for a different version of RHEL (or any other distribution) will work on your version, but it's very unlikely because the package dependencies and libraries the package was build against are different in your distribution. So yes, EPEL 8 package won't work on RHEL 7.
If you find a package that is build for one version of EPEL and not for another version of EPEL, you can always try to ask the package maintainer to build it for your version too, simply report an RFE to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/ under the "Fedora EPEL" product. But if you want a new package for EPEL 7 your are out of luck because EPEL 7 is now EOL.
